# Order of a numerical iteration method

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, fixed-point-theorems, finite-differences, numerical-calculus

Suppose that we have the definition of order $p$ of a numerical method as in the first snippet below. Now I want to prove that for a one-point iterative method this order $p$ is a **positive integer**. To that end, [Ralston](http://62.182.86.140/main/903000/4bb55429c193eb542401a75bdd262d18/%28International%20series%20in%20pure%20and%20applied%20mathematics%29%20Anthony%20Ralston_%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20A%20first%20course%20in%20numerical%20analysis-McGraw-Hill%20%20%281978%29.pdf) in the theorem $8.1$ takes a Taylor expansion as in the next snippet below. But there I got stuck: in formula  $(8.4-4)$
in the r.h.s. he says $$\lim_{i\to\infty} \dfrac{\left|x_{i+1}-\alpha\right|}{\left|x_i-\alpha\right|^{p}}=\frac{1}{p!}F^{(p)}(\alpha)\neq 0.$$
Now **why** this equality after $\lim$ holds with $F^{(p)}(\alpha)$ is evaluated at $\alpha$ while $(8.4-3)$ is evaulated at $\xi$ ?

Last but not least if $$F^{(j)}(\alpha)\neq 0$$ for some $j=1,\ldots,p-1$ **then** $F(x)$
**cannot** be of order $p$. Why this is so, what is intuition for this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ralston assumes that $F$ has "sufficiently many derivatives" and so is probably also assuming that $F^{(p)}$ is continuous. Since $\xi$ lies between $x_i$ and $\alpha$, and $x_i \to \alpha$, then that necessarily implies that $\xi \to \alpha$ and so $F^{(p)}(\xi)\to F^{(p)}(\alpha)$ as $i\to\infty$.

To answer your second question, suppose that $F^{(j)}(\alpha) \neq 0$ for some $j < p$. Then, assuming the rest of the derivatives of $F$ of order less than $j$ are zero, we find via a Taylor expansion up to order $j$ that
$$F(x_i) = x_{i+1} = \alpha +  \frac{1}{j!}F^{(j)}(\xi)(x-\alpha)^{j}$$
where $\xi$ lies in the interval between $x_i$ and $\alpha$. Therefore, we have
$$\frac{|x_{i+1}-\alpha|}{|x_{i}-\alpha|^j} = \frac{1}{j!}F^{(j)}(\xi). $$
Taking the limit as $i\to \infty$ then yields
$$\lim_{i\to\infty} \frac{|x_{i+1}-\alpha|}{|x_{i}-\alpha|^j} = \frac{1}{j!}F^{(j)}(\alpha)$$
indicating that the order of convergence is at most $j$. Since $j<p$, we cannot have $p^{\text{th}}$ order convergence.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. How have you derived that the order of convergence is **at most** $j$ from the fact that it is $j$ ?

Comment: I'm just trying to get across that since the order of convergence is $j$ (under the hypothesis I stated) we cannot get convergence orders larger than $j$ i.e., we cannot get $p^{\text{th}}$ order convergence.

Comment: I'm sorry my English is poor. What do you mean by "trying to get across that" ? Is there a real reason why $$\lim_{i\to\infty} \frac{|x_{i+1}-\alpha|}{|x_{i}-\alpha|^j} = \frac{1}{j!}F^{(j)}(\alpha)$$ implies that not $$\lim_{i\to\infty} \frac{|x_{i+1}-\alpha|}{|x_{i}-\alpha|^{j+\epsilon}} \neq C > 0 $$ fro any $\epsilon > 0 $ ?

Comment: Sure. Look at the Taylor series argument. We had that

$$x_{i+1} = \alpha + F^{(j)}(\xi)(x_i-\alpha)^j$$

and so

$$(x_{i+1}-\alpha) =  F^{(j)}(\xi)(x_i-\alpha)^j$$

If we divide both sides by $(x_i-\alpha)^{j+\varepsilon}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, we get that
$$\frac{(x_{i+1}-\alpha)}{(x_i - \alpha)^{j+\varepsilon}} =  F^{(j)}(\xi)(x_i-\alpha)^{-\varepsilon}$$

Comment: So the r.h.s. will not be some real number $C$ in the limit but $\infty$, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily, the above just tells you that the iteration is not converging at any rate greater than $j$.

Comment: You are telling me exactly that the limit $$\lim_{i\to \infty}\frac{|x_{i+1}-\alpha|}{|x_i-\alpha|^{j+\epsilon}}=F^{(j)}(\xi)\lim_{i\to\infty}(x_i-\alpha)^{-\epsilon}$$ might not actually exist at all ?